# Use "sudo su" but avoid having root as file owner

Tags: sudo, root, su

I have a long script which I want to execute, a lot of commands in the script need `sudo`.

To avoid using `sudo`, I put `sudo su` at the beginning of the script.
The problem with this is that this makes all files created through the script have `root` as the owner.

Is there any way to avoid having files owned by `root` without having to manually set `sudo` for each command that needs it?

(I know that `sudo su` is bad practice, but this is my raspberrypi, not an important server)

Comment: Have you tried running the script with something like `sudo sh myscript`. Does that produce the result you are looking for?

Comment: It's not so much that `sudo su` is bad practice as that it is ugly and inelegant. Why use two commands (`sudo  su`) when one (`sudo -i`) will do?

Comment: @PonJar that produces the same result

@terdon it seems like this will only execute the rest of the script after i manually exit the `su` shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the script is predominantly something that needs to run as root, make it so:

```
sudo myscript
```

Within the script, on the lines that must not be root, use `sudo` with a specified user:

```
sudo -u user some_command with parameters
```

It's not particularly difficult to have a script restart itself under `sudo` if it's not running as root, so you can then even dispense with the initial `sudo` to start it.

Note that nowhere should you need `su` if you're using `sudo`

Comment: So basically the opposite?
Instead of running as my user, and using `sudo` when I want to do something as root, I do everything as root except for when I specify this?

Comment: @KevinHoltkamp if the script needs to be root for most (or much) of its actions, run it as root. If it needs to be root only for one or two moments, run it as a normal user.